# Cassandra : Using output of one query as input to another query

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I have two tables one is users and other is expired_users.

users columns-> id, name, age
expired_users columns -> id, name

I want to execute the following query.

delete from users where id in (select id from expired_users);

This query works fine with SQL related databases. I want find a solution to solve this in cassandra.

PS: I don't want to add any extra columns in the tables.

Answer (score 2):

While designing cassandra data model, we cannot think exactly like RDBMS .
Design like this --

```
create table users (
id int,
name text,
age int,
expired boolean static,
primary key (id,name)
);
```

To mark a user as expired -- Just insert the same row again

```
insert into users (id,name,age,expired) values (100,'xyz',80,true);
```

you don't have to update or delete the row, just insert it again, previous column values will get overridden.

Comment: This doesn't solve my purpose. I cannot change the existing table structure.

Comment: @Bhanu Boppana It would be better if you add the table defination in question then.

Comment: I have added the columns I have in my tables in the question. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I don't think you have better choice than alter table, otherwise you have to select each user from expired_users and delete entry in users at application level. With cassandra we cannot think like joining tables as database level. Also, deleting a rwo will create tomb stone.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to is to use join as a filter for your delete statement, and this is not what the Cassandra model is built for.

AFAIK there is no way to perform this using cql. If you want to perform this action without changing the schema - run external script in any language that has drivers for Cassandra.